# How can I get my Hipchat Integration on Heroku to authenticate?

Tags: heroku, oauth, hipchat

I followed the step-by-step guide [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/hipchat/tutorials/getting-started-with-atlassian-connect-express-node-js).

I made a simple app that posts a message to the rooms the Integration is installed on per a regex (as described in the tutorial above).

When I initially add the Integration to a hipchat room, it works fine.  However, after a period of time it stops working.

The following error appears in my Heroku logs:

```
JWT verification error: 400 Request can't be verified without an OAuth secret
```

I assume something with my configuration is wrong or my lack-of-use-of-OAuth, but after googling around I can't find any specific answers on what it *should* look like.

My config.json looks like this:

```
    "production": {
    "usePublicKey": true,
    "port": "$PORT",
    "store": {
        "adapter": "jugglingdb",
        "type": "sqlite3",
        "database": "store.db"
    },
    "whitelist": [
        "*.hipchat.com"
    ]
},
```

And my request handler looks like this:

```
app.post('/foo',
    addon.authenticate(),
    function (req, res) {
      hipchat.sendMessage(req.clientInfo, req.identity.roomId, 'bar')
        .then(function (data) {
          res.sendStatus(200);
        });
    }
);
```

Any specific direction on configuration and use of Oauth for Hipchat and Heroku would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't used the jugglingdb adapter with Heroku and don't know if you can actually look into the database, but it seems like somewhere along the way `clientInfo` disappears from the store.

My suggestion is to start testing locally with ngrok and redis, so that you can troubleshoot locally and then push the working code to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks so much Nick.  It was indeed an issue with my database connection.  I'll submit an answer that has what exactly was wrong, but your comment gave me the push I needed in the right direction of "where exactly should I start investigating next".  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that Matt!
Would you mind adding this to your thread on answers.atlassian, where I originally found it?
For some reason, I wasn't able to comment there: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/56491009/how-can-i-get-my-hipchat-integration-on-heroku-to-authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Three things I needed to do in order to fix my problem:

1. Install the [Heroku Redis add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) for my Heroku App. (confirm that the Environment Variable for ($REDIS_URL) was added to your app settings).
2. Add this line to my app.js file:

   ac.store.register('redis', require('atlassian-connect-express-redis'));
3. Change the production.store object in the config.json to be the following:

   "store": {
           "adapter": "redis",
           "url": "$REDIS_URL"
       },